# The same code of the IntentService cannot start server in Android 5.1 (API 22) but works well in Android 4.2

Tags: android

I run the following code in Android 4.2, click Button1 then Button2, the result is Ok

[image]

When I run the same code in Android 5.1 (API 22), click Button1 then Button2, it seems that IntentService is not worked ,why?

[image]

You can download https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ou0ctjcmzqluyh/MyApplication.zip?dl=0 to test.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntentServiceDemo.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("param", "oper1");
                startServiceIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                startService(startServiceIntent);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent startServiceIntent2 =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntentServiceDemo.class);
                Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();
                bundle2.putString("param", "oper2");
                startServiceIntent2.putExtras(bundle2);
                startService(startServiceIntent2);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btnClose).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               finish();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.dodata.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


      <service android:name=".IntentServiceDemo">

      </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**IntentServiceDemo.cs**

```
public class IntentServiceDemo extends IntentService {

    public IntentServiceDemo() {
        super("IntentServiceDemo");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("onBind");
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e("MY", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.e("MY", "onStart");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("MY", "onStartCommand");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void setIntentRedelivery(boolean enabled) {
        super.setIntentRedelivery(enabled);
        Log.e("MY", "setIntentRedelivery");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getExtras().getString("param");

        Log.e("MY", "TO " + action);

        if (action.equals("oper1")) {
            Log.e("MY", "Operation1");
        }else if (action.equals("oper2")) {
            Log.e("MY", "Operation2");
        }

        /*
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("MY", "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.dodata.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: how you filter your tomcat? i think its running but with different process id. if not, then it will throw warning or exception in your logcat

Comment: I use  Log.e to filter

Comment: You can download  https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ou0ctjcmzqluyh/MyApplication.zip?dl=0 to test